Can we have a `mental-illness` and `personality-disorder` tag?

Can we have a mental-illness and personality-disorder tag?

I am posting a lot of questions and would like to add these tags. I think, as the site grows, these are tags many people would use on google.

Calling Artem! We have a tag question! :-)

a wild Artem appears what is wrong with the abnormal-psychology, clinical-psychology, and psychiatry tags? I fear that the two tags you are proposing have too much potential for abuse with users that don't bother to read the FAQ (i.e. almost all new users) asking medical advice and self-help questions on these tags; we have specific policies against both types of questions. As such, I would advise against these tags so as we don't promote more bad questions, but my opinion should not carry much weight since I have not really been contributing to the community for a while now :(.

@Artem I agree about [tag:abnormal-psychology] but which would personality disorder fall under? That I think might be signifigant enough for it's own tag, I am unsure.

In clinical psychology, "illness" and "disorder" are used synonymously in the literature as well as in diagnostic manuals. It would be counterproductive to differentiate the terms here.
Since "mental disorder" and "mental illness" are synonyms, a "personality disorder", which is a class of mental disorders, is a class of mental illnesses. If we introduced "personality disorder" as a separate tag, then we would need to introduce tags for all other classes of mental disorders as well (of which there are around 400 in the DSM), which I think is overkill with the current scarcity of relevant questions.
Since clinical psychology is the field that deals with mental disorders of all kinds, I don't think that a separate tag "mental disorder" is necessary, because no question is possible that deals with the object of research but not the discipline.
In short, I don't see that we need any of the proposed tags, because the existing tags cover the related questions with adequate distinctiveness.

Just my opinion: 

personality-disorder makes sense to me given that this refers to a particular class of disorder.
mental-illness is probably adequately captured by abnormal-psychology or possibly clinical-psychology or psychiatry.

